# Windows 8 "Modern UI" applications show as offline

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app

When I start Windows 8 and the home screen comes on I can't get onto Bing because it says I am offline, the same happens with Internet Explorer.

When I try to get into any app it says it is offline but my computer clearly says I am connected.

If I go into the desktop mode applications then the internet works fine.

Comment: I have tried to clarify your question, if I have changed the meaning too much then you should be able to edit it back but I believe this is what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in my case the DNS Client service was stopped. Run the services MMC snapin (services.msc) and set the start type of the DNS client service to automatic.

Comment: For me, setting the DNS Client Service to manual was enough to make things work.  Edit: Actually, it looks like it gets triggered and starts when I open a Modern App.

Comment: I have no idea why I had DNS Client Service "disabled" (VPN, maybe?) but after setting to Manual it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: @mikiqex nice to hear that this works for you :)